# get the return value of function in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a 2 files. file1 and file2. In file1 i have input box. so, i am getting this value in a javascript function like this

```
     <td>
         <input  onmouseleave="detect(this.value)" id="myqty"  value="'.$items['qty'].'">
     </td>
     <script>
            var retVal; 
            function detect(value)
            {

                 retVal=value;
                 return retVal

             }
       </script>
```

I am returning that value. So in file2 i have javascript where i want to receive that returned value. how can i?

file2

```
 $(document).on('mouseleave', '#myqty', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
   var returnValue= detect();
});
```

but in  `var returnValue= detect();`  i am getting nothing.

Comment: Since you are using JQuery, you can get the required value as `$("#myqty").val()`

Comment: i want get the value of returned value of javascript function. how can i?

Comment: You aren't doing any processing with that value, so why not use `$("#myqty").val()` whenever you want the `input` value?

Comment: But you have not done any change in function so its better to take it using `$("#myqty").val()`

Comment: javascript can't *get* something from a different web page directly like that at all

Comment: $("#myqty").val() if i use this,  it gets the value of the first row. i have many rows. and when i change the text field value it should get that value. that why i used javascript return function

Comment: Or else you store that value in global variable and use it in different page

Comment: You cannot have same ID at other places. IDs are unique. Instead use class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe its because function is expecting a parameter. Try this instead:-

```
$(document).on('mouseleave', '#myqty', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
   var returnValue= detect($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `class` and this how your code can be tweaked and updated:

```js
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.myqty', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
  <input class="myqty" value="123">
</td>
<td>
  <input class="myqty" value="324">
</td>
<td>
  <input class="myqty" value="36546">
</td>
<td>
  <input class="myqty" value="654656">
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass parameter in here 
var returnValue= detect();

First you dont need 2 functions for this. Why are you using 2 functions for this.
You want quantity in another js file you can do all the code there only.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myqty').mouseleave(function(){

                var retVal= $('#myqty').val();
                alert(retVal);
        });
 });
```